# Is there an integral point in the group generated by an rational point?

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over rational field. Let $P=(a/d^2,b/d^3)\in E(\mathbb{Q})$ and
$$G=\{P,2P,3P,4P,\cdots\}.$$
Is there an integral point $Q\in G?$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I presume that (1) $E$ is meant to be in minimal form with integer coefficients,
else you can change coordinates to put $P$ and $nP$ anywhere, and that
(2) $P$ is not itself integral (i.e. $d>1$), else $Q=P$ works.

Then the answer is No, because $d^2$ and $d^3$ divide the denominators
of $x(nP)$ and $y(nP)$ for all $n$.

This is a known property of "elliptic divisibility sequences".
One way to think about it is that $p|d$ means that $P$ is $p$-adically
near the identity point $\infty$ on $E$ (and $p^e|d$ for $e>1$ makes $P$ even nearer),
and then any multiple of $P$ is at least as close.

Comment: Noam, regarding your point (1), I think it's enough that the equation for $E$ have integer coefficients. It's not necessary that it be minimal in order to deduce that $d(P)\mid d(nP)$.

Answer (score 6):

You probably meant to specify that the coordinates of $P$ are in lowest terms, and that $d\ge2$. Then, as Noam indicates, the answer is no. And it doesn't matter if the equation is minimal, as long as it has integer coefficients and as long as you start with a point $P$ having non-integer coordinates.

A good way to study this question is via the formal group, see for example Chapters 4 and 7 of my book *The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*. Assuming that you are on a minimal Weierstrass equation, one can prove something even stronger, namely if $p\mid d$ and if we write $nP=(a_n/d_n^2,b_n/d_n^3)$ in lowest terms, then the power of $p$ dividing $d_n$ is exactly
$$  \operatorname{ord}_p(d_n) = \operatorname{ord}(d) + \operatorname{ord}(n). $$
This shows that $d\mid d_n$ for every $n$, as Noam indicated, but is considerably more precise.

Lots more is known about the sequence $(d_n)$, which is called an *elliptic divisibility sequence*. For example, there is an $N$ so that for every index $n>N$ the term $d_n$ in the sequence is divisible by a prime that doesn't divide any of the earlier $d_i$ with $i<n$. On the other hand, it is not known whether there are infinitely many primes $q$ such that if $d_n$ is the first term in the sequence divisible by $q$, then $q^2\mid d_n$. (These are the elliptic analogue of Wieferich primes.)

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily. In fact, if the answer was yes, there would be an easy (yet time consuming) algorithm for computing Mordell-Weil ranks, which we don't have.

The lowest conductor example with positive rank and no integral points is this [elliptic curve](http://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/189.b1).

```
sage: E = EllipticCurve('189b3')
sage: E.rank()
1
sage: E.gens()
[(-143/4 : -3/8 : 1)]
sage: E.integral_points()
[]
```

I looked it up by typing this into sage:

```
sage: for E in cremona_curves(1..1000):
    if E.rank() > 0:
        if len(E.integral_points())<3:
            print E.cremona_label(), E.rank(), E.integral_points()
```

This functionality should be helpful in answering a lot of other questions of this type you might have about elliptic curves. Some can even by answered simply by using the [search feature on LMFDB](http://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/), but this isn't one of them. You can read more about Cremona's database (now up to conductor at least 300,000) in this [report](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masgaj/papers/ecdb_ants.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, but I mean is it possible? Indeed I'm looking for an example, which there is such integral point! I can't find such example!!!